# How to select multiple lines using java Selenium automation testing?

Tags: automated-tests

I tried to select multiple lines using selenium automation like below.

```
this.selectLineInTable(Locator.LOCATOR_LIST, "name", t1.getName()).
this.selectLineInTable(Locator.LOCATOR_LIST,"name",t2.getName()));
```

but its not working. Can anyone help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: youy need to post what sort of elements you are clicking and your coding approach to handle that

Comment: need to select mutiple rows at a time using selenium LOCATORS by element name;, and for selecting a single line i am following this coding approach --- this.selectLineInTable(scLocatorBody, key, value);

Comment: use actions class to keyDown (CONTROL) button and along with it keep clicking elements with it which you want to select and then release (CONTROL) button; in which language are you writing your scripts?

Comment: can you give some demo code for example;

Answer (score 0):

try something like below:

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("first element to select"))).click().build().perform();

act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("second element to select"))).click().release().build().perform();
```

Comment: Actions act = new Actions(driver);           
              String m1 = this.selectLineInTable(Constant.LOCATOR_LIST_MOFULL, "name",psv.getName());//1st element
              String m2=this.selectLineInTable(Constant.LOCATOR_LIST_MOFULL, "name",psTest.getName());// 2nd element
           
            act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.name(m1))).click().build().perform();

            act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.name(m2))).click().release().build().perform();

Comment: i tryied this;;protected String selectLineInTable(String scLocatorBody, String key, String value) throws Exception {
        String scLocatorLine = this.findLineInTable(scLocatorBody, key, value);        if (scLocatorLine == null) {           
            this.logError("The row [" + key + "=" + value + "] does not exist", null);    } else { StringBuffer lRow = new StringBuffer();           lRow.append(scLocatorLine).append("col[fieldName=").append(key).append("]/");            this.clickOnElement(lRow.toString());
            sleep(500);        }        return scLocatorLine;    }

Comment: getting exception ;;;Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"scLocator=//ListGrid[ID=\"ssr_grid\"]/body/row[0]/"}

Comment: Check your locators

Comment: locator is correct; is this code correct;                                                  
String m2=this.selectLineInTable(Constant.LOCATOR_LIST_MOFULL,"name",psTest.getName());// 2nd element;      act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.name(m1))).click().build().perform();

Comment: your loactor is not correct org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementExceptionorg.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementExceptionorg.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException means your locator is not able to find the element because that doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

```
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);           
          String m1 = this.selectLineInTable(Constant.LOCATOR_LIST_MOFULL, "name",psv.getName());//1st element
          String m2=this.selectLineInTable(Constant.LOCATOR_LIST_MOFULL, "name",psTest.getName());// 2nd element

        act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.name(m1))).click().build().perform();

        act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.name(m2))).click().release().build().perform();
```

protected String selectLineInTable(String scLocatorBody, String key, String value) throws Exception {
        String scLocatorLine = this.findLineInTable(scLocatorBody, key, value);

```
    if (scLocatorLine == null) {
        // No line for key / value
        this.logError("The row [" + key + "=" + value + "] does not exist", null);
    } else {
        // Click on the line
        StringBuffer lRow = new StringBuffer();
       lRow.append(scLocatorLine).append("col[fieldName=").append(key).append("]/");
        this.clickOnElement(lRow.toString());
        sleep(500);
    }

    return scLocatorLine;
}
```

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"scLocator=//ListGrid[ID=\"ssr_grid\"]/body/row[0]/"}